# BeautifulSoup Webcrapping error / no code running

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried running this code to do some `web-scraping` and it doesn't want to work :(
- Using windows 10
- Pycharm editor
 -(Running code inside the pycharm python console thingo)

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.danmurphys.com.au/current-offers?filters=variety(beer)&size=120'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='ResultsContainer')
print(results.prettify())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2127, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1961, in main
    setup = process_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_command_line_handling.py", line 136, in process_command_line
    setup['file'] = argv[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: your exception asked `IndexError: list index out of range` which becomes from `setup['file'] = argv[i]`. You need to show the whole code that give an answer

Answer (score 0):

If the "soup" is not empty most likely there is no such element in the page or it is loaded by javascript.